# Flatten dictionary in Python (functional style)

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn how to write functional code with Python and have found some tutorials online. Please note that I know Python is not a promoter for functional programming. I just want to try it out. [One tutorial](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/functional-programming.html) in particular gives this as an exercise:

> Write a function flatten_dict to flatten a nested dictionary by
>   joining the keys with . character.

So I decided to give it a try. Here is what I have and it works fine:

```
def flatten_dict(d, result={}, prv_keys=[]):

    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten_dict(v, result, prv_keys + [k])
        else:
            result['.'.join(prv_keys + [k])] = v

return result
```

I'd like to know whether this is the best way to solve the problem in python. In particular, I really don't like to pass a list of previous keys to the recursive call.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your solution really isn't at all functional. You should return a flattened dict and then merge that into your current dictionary. You should also not modify the dictionary, instead create it with all the values it should have. Here is my approach:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
            else:
                yield key, value

    return dict(items())
```

Alternative which avoids yield

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    def expand(key, value):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return [ (key + '.' + k, v) for k, v in flatten_dict(value).items() ]
        else:
            return [ (key, value) ]

    items = [ item for k, v in d.items() for item in expand(k, v) ]

    return dict(items)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to iterate through the result during each recursive step but it returns an error stating the size of the dictionary changed. I'm new to python and I barely understand yield. Is it because yield creates the value on the fly without storing them that the code is not blocked anymore?

Comment: One thing though. I did return a flattened dict and merged it into a current dictionary, which is the flattened result of the original dictionary. I'd like to know why it was not functional at all...

Comment: @LimH., if you got that error you were modifying the dictionary you were iterating over. If you are trying to be functional, you shouldn't be modifying dictionaries at all.

Comment: No, you did not return a flattened dict and merge it. You ignore the return value of your recursive function call. Your function modifies what is passed to it which is exactly that which you aren't supposed to do in functional style.

Comment: yield does create values on the fly, but that has nothing to do with why this works. It works because it creates new objects and never attempts to modify the existing ones.

Comment: I see my mistakes now. Thank you very much :) I thought I was passing copies of result to the function. In fact, I think the author of the tutorial I'm following makes the same mistake, at least with the flatten_list function: http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/functional-programming.html#example-flatten-a-list

Comment: Unfortunately, both versions are bugged for 3+ levels of recursion.

Comment: @JohnOptionalSmith, I see the problem in the second version, but the first seems to work for me... test case?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Try it with `a = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : { 'leprous' : 'bilateral' }, 'c' : { 'sigh' : 'somniphobia'} }` (actually triggers the bug with 2-level recursion)

Comment: My bad ! CopyPaste error ! Your first version is fine.

Comment: Thanks for this nice code snippet @WinstonEwert! Could you explain why you defined a function in a function here? Is there a benefit to doing this instead of defining the same functions outside of one another?

Comment: @zelusp, the benefit is organizational, the function inside the function is part of of the implementation of the outer function, and putting the function inside makes it clear and prevents other functions from using it.

Comment: [This link](https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) helped me understand better

Answer (score 9):

Beside avoiding mutations, functional mindset demands to split into elementary functions, along two axes:

1. Decouple responsibilities.
2. By case analysis (eg pattern matching). Here scalar vs dict.

Regarding 1, nested dict traversal has nothing to do with the requirement to create dot separated keys. We've better return a list a keys, and concatenate them afterward. Thus, if you change your mind (using another separator, making abbreviations...), you don't have to dive in the iterator code -and worse, modify it.

```
def iteritems_nested(d):
  def fetch (suffixes, v0) :
    if isinstance(v0, dict):
      for k, v in v0.items() :
        for i in fetch(suffixes + [k], v):  # "yield from" in python3.3
          yield i
    else:
      yield (suffixes, v0)

  return fetch([], d)

def flatten_dict(d) :
  return dict( ('.'.join(ks), v) for ks, v in iteritems_nested(d))
  #return { '.'.join(ks) : v for ks,v in iteritems_nested(d) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me see if I get this right. Basically there are two strategies here. One is to recursively construct the dictionary result and one is to construct the suffixes. I used the second approach but my mistake was that I passed a reference of the result down the recursive chains but the key part is correct. Is that right? Winston Etwert used the first approach right? What's wrong with his code?

Comment: The point is to (a) collect keys until deepest level and (b) concatenate them. You indeed did separate the two (although packed in the same function). Winston concatenate on the fly without modifying (mutating) anything, but an issue lies in recursion.

Comment: My bad : Winston's implementation with yield is ok !

Comment: Is packing multiple objectives in the same function bad? I.e., is it bad style or is it conceptually incorrect?

Comment: @LimH. [Both !](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/courses/cs345/whyfp.pdf). It can be necessary for performance reason, since Python won't neither inline nor defer computation (lazy programming). To alleviate this point, you can follow the opposite approach : provide to the iterator the way to collect keys -via a folding function- (strategy pattern, kind of).